# Calculate length of road in a Polygon

Tags: gis, arcgis, qgis

I have this interesting challenge in my work, i have shape files of road networks, and another shape-File containing area boundaries, is there any tool that i can use to get length of roads that lies inside each polygon?
I have access to both QGIS and ArcGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably better asked on gis stackoverflow.

That said, this is a multi-stage problem. I'd suggest something like:

1. Clip the roads layer by the polygon layer, keeping the polygon id for each road.
2. Measure the length of the now-clipped roads.
3. Sum up the road lengths, grouping by the polygon_id
4. Join the now-measured,-summed-and-clipped roads layer back to the polygon layer.

This will give you what you want.
If you don't know how to use QGIS/ArcGIS, try googling for tutorials (or get work to splurge on training). There are plenty that cover the above functions.